# Execute stored procedures in SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table `tblDashboard` with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDashboard]
(
    [DashboardID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](2047) NOT NULL,
    [StoredProcedureName] [nvarchar](511) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Dashboard] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DashboardID] ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For each dashboard item, I have a stored procedure attached to it. I would have to execute the corresponding stored procedure set against the dashboard item.

The output I need basically is in the below format

```
SELECT 
    DashboardID, Name, 
    <stored procedure output> 
FROM 
    tblDashboard
```

I know it is not possible to have `EXEC` statement inside `SELECT` query but looking for advice / alternate ways to achieve this output. Thanks

All stored procedures return a `nvarchar(MAX)` type value. Should I change each of the stored procedures to functions and call inside `SELECT` query?

I have changed my stored procedures to functions and added [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44d28/1) to help execute my functions.

Instead of Function Name in the last column, I need that function output.  Is this possible with dynamic query?

Comment: What are you expecting in the SP output result? The way you've got it, it looks like you're expecting the result in one big blob. Would a big XML result work?

Comment: Do all Stored procedures return same type of output?

Comment: I have updated my question with the answers; it returns same output

Comment: Create a scalar valued function instead.  If you can.

Comment: What is the output of the stored procedure?  Is it a single scalar value (int, char, bit, etc.)?  Is it a record set?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, I'm also thinking the same; I could convert the SPs to Functions

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I changed my SP to function but how do I dynamically execute function? I can't hard code function in SELECT; the function name is in the column of the table!

Comment: I have added http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44d28/1, not sure how to run function inside select query - SELECT DashboardID, Name, FunctionName FROM tblDashboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would be rewrite the stored procedure as a `TVF`. This way you would be able to do:

```
SELECT  dashboardId, name, tvf.*
FROM    dashboard
CROSS APPLY
        my_tvf(dashboardId) tvf
```

If you can't do that and if your stored procedure only returns one resultset, you need to declare a table variable or a temporary table (same layout as the procedure's resultset), then declare a cursor for dashboard entries and append to the table in a loop:

```
DECLARE cr_dashboard CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT  *
FROM    dashboard

DECLARE @id INT

OPEN    cr_dashboard

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
        FETCH   cr_dashboard
        INTO    @id

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
                BREAK

        INSERT
        INTO    @tv
        EXEC    my_sp @id
END

CLOSE   cr_dashboard

DEALLOCATE
        cr_dashboard
```

Then you need to join your `@tv` with `dashboard` (provided that the stored proc returns the dashboard id in the resultset somewhere).

Comment: I have added an sqlfiddle in the question changing stored procedure to function. Do you think of a different approach instead of using cursors?  Thanks

Comment: hmm... it is not that simple; the functions are completely different;  I can't combine the logic of all functions into one function and return my output

Comment: @techspider: tough luck

Comment: I'm thinking may be adding a generic wrapper function and call the actual functions hard coded inside wrapper function with multiple IF conditions

Comment: @techspider: that might work. We might have even given you advice on how to do that if you would have been less cryptic about your functions layout and purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109090/discussion-between-techspider-and-quassnoi).